# Lenovo ix4-300d - apt-get not working

Tags: debian, lamp, network-attached-storage

I just bought a NAS (Lenovo ix4-300d) that's running Debian, and I just found out how to enable SSH. I want to install Apache, MySQL and PHP for local development.

When I'm trying to use `apt-get`, I get the following error:

```
login as: root
root@192.168.1.76's password:
root@ix4-300d:/# apt-get install php5
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (2 No such file or directory)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
root@ix4-300d:/# su
sh-3.2# apt-get install php5
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (2 No such file or directory)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Even though I `su`ed to get root access, it still tells me I'm not root when trying to use `apt-get`.

How do I fix `apt-get` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like for some reason, Debian was unable to open up the lock file apt uses. This seems to be a massively common thing [according to Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Could+not+open+lock+file+/var/lib/dpkg/lock+-+open+%282+No+such+file+or+directory%29&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

[This seems to be a logical solution](http://shujihao.blogspot.sg/2012/10/ubuntu-dpkg-no-lock-and-status-file.html) - that `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` dosen't exist - so checking for the existence of and creating `/var/lib/dpkg/` might help.

If it also complains that `/var/lib/dpkg/status` doesn't exist, you should be able to copy it from a backup by doing `cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status` as root.